# Linker failed for xamarin.android project with xamarin.insights integrated

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, portable-class-library, xamarin-linker

I have `Xamarin.Android` app which leverage `PCL` support and `Xamarin.Insights` component.
Unfortunately in the release configuration with the linker option `SDK Assemblies` it wouldn't build.
If I disable the linker everything works just fine but I need the linker for the release configuration.

```
(PackageForAndroid) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets (_LinkAssemblies target) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: error : Error executing task LinkAssemblies: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'System.Void Xamarin.Insights::Initialize(System.String)' (defined in 'MyApp.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from 'MyApp.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved.
            : error : Error building target _LinkAssemblies: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
            MyApp.Android/MyApp.Android.csproj: error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Please advise.